# No longer see Docker build output properly!

Tags: docker

I am using the latest version of Docker Desktop on Windows (**Docker Engine version v19.03.13**).

After the last update, the output of `docker build .` has changed! *It is now harder to debug what is going on*.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# set base image as the dotnet 3.1 SDK.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env

# set the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD
# instructions that follows the WORKDIR instruction.
WORKDIR /app

# debug purposes - see where we are
RUN pwd

# our current working directory within the container is /app
# we now copy all the files (from local machine) to /app (in the container).
COPY . ./

# debug purposes - list files in current folder
RUN ls -la

# run unit tests within the solution.
RUN dotnet test Phoneden.sln

# again, on the container (we are in /app folder)
# we now publish the project into a folder called 'out'.
RUN dotnet publish Phoneden.Web/Phoneden.Web.csproj -c Release -o out

# debug purposes - list files in current folder
RUN ls -la

# set base image as the dotnet 3.1 runtime.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime

# telling the application what port to run on.
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5005

# set the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD
# instructions that follows the WORKDIR instruction.
WORKDIR /app

# copy the contents of /app/out in the `build-env` and paste it in the
# `/app` directory of the new runtime container.
COPY --from=build-env /app/Phoneden.Web/out .

# set the entry point into the application.
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Phoneden.Web.dll", "-seed"]
```

When I run `docker build --no-cache .` I get the following:

```
jwan@home-desktop MSYS /c/code/phoneden (upgrade/net-3.1)
$ docker build --no-cache .
[+] Building 38.9s (16/16) FINISHED
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.3s
 => => transferring context: 96.50kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.2s
 => [build-env 1/8] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1@sha256:1d96e460ac4af00ffc41c5d4a27b503f2589098c84b6ca10d09e0f7ef6e31689                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [runtime 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1@sha256:41ece4e6218d5f2c66191c4bd8b8dda060ea3b1512353fe1185e239121458ab5                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [build-env 2/8] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [runtime 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [build-env 3/8] RUN pwd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.3s
 => [build-env 4/8] COPY . ./                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.3s
 => [build-env 5/8] RUN ls -la                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.3s
 => [build-env 6/8] RUN dotnet test Phoneden.sln                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  17.7s
 => [build-env 7/8] RUN dotnet publish Phoneden.Web/Phoneden.Web.csproj -c Release -o out                                                                                                                                                                                         19.5s
 => [build-env 8/8] RUN ls -la                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.6s
 => ERROR [runtime 3/3] COPY --from=build-env /app/Phoneden.Web/out .                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
------
 > [runtime 3/3] COPY --from=build-env /app/Phoneden.Web/out .:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to compute cache key: "/app/Phoneden.Web/out" not found: not found
```

As you can see, it is not listing the result of the debug commands I added.

How can I get the output to be verbose like it was before the update?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the output from buildkit. You can run buildkit based builds with a different output syntax:

```
$ docker build --help
...
  --progress string         Set type of progress output (auto, plain, tty). Use plain to show container output
                            (default "auto")
```

In your command, that would be:

```
docker build --progress=plain .
```

Or you can disable buildkit by setting `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` in your shell:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build .
```

Comment: This is no longer possible: 
`DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
BuildKit is currently disabled; enable it by removing the DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
environment-variable.`

Comment: @sage What do you mean by "this"? `--progress=plain` or only disabling buildkit?